# How Can You Describe Someone Leaving A Room In an Unwilling, Emotional Manner?

Tags: synonyms, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I'm writing a short story about a young girl that has emotional issues, such as severe depression and anorexia. I'm trying to come up with a word that best expresses her disinterest and unwillingness to go to work with all the skinny, LA-typical blond girls. Right now, what I have:

> Arriving at work I tossed my faded knockoff leather bag on the table in the back and checked my phone one more time before heading out onto the retail floor. Three missed calls from Mom. I put my phone back in my pocket and headed to the front.

Specifically, this is what I'm referring to, but any constructive criticism is welcome:

> I put my phone back in my pocket and ***headed*** to the front.

So, if you have any suggestions on phrasing or sentence structure, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks For Reading,

Luna

Comment: There are many possible alternatives for your context - have a look at [synonyms for ***flounce***](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/flounce), for example *(stormed out, stomped off, etc.).* It partly depends on *exactly* how you left *(scurried out, sidled towards, slunk off?)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps ***[dragged](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drag) myself*** would work for you. From Oxford Dictionaries:

> 1.2 (**drag oneself**) Go somewhere wearily, reluctantly, or with difficulty.

I think this gets across your character's great dislike of a job that she, nonetheless, has to go to. So:

> I put my phone back in my pocket and **dragged myself** to the front.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing your verb with another verb, which may or may not fully fit the bill, consider modifying it with an adverb to convey the way the action is being carried out.

**Reluctant**

> [(MW)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reluctant): feeling or showing aversion, hesitation, or willingness: *reluctant to get involved*
>
> [(dictionary.com)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reluctant): 1. unwilling; disinclined: *a reluctant candidate.*

adverb form: **reluctantly**. Therefore, the resultant sentence would read:

> I put my phone back in my pocket and ***reluctantly*** headed to the front.